# How to set selector in expandable listivew on Group in android

Tags: android, android-widget, selector, expandablelistview

I want to set selector on its `groupView` but when I click selector on `groupView` it goes to `childView` in `expandable listview.`.
Here is my `expandable listview`.

```
     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLeft"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll
        />
```

Here  is my group_indication.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Here is my normal.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

actually I want to set custom color on `groupView` in expandable listview but when I click on   `groupView`, custom color set on `groupView` 's `childView`. I have attach screen shot which problem I am getting now in which Transaction History is `GroupView` and My Transaction is `childView` . Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem by Prakash Gavade's answer. [here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318642/highlight-for-selected-item-in-expandable-list/15587431#15587431). In expandable listiview adapter, I have added below code.

```
     @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tvUserName = null;
        ImageView imgMenuIcon = null;

        View drawerView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (groupPosition == 0)
        {
            drawerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_image, parent, false);
            ImageView ivProfilePic = (ImageView) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
            tvUserName = (TextView) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.tvFname);
            TextView tvLname = (TextView) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.tvLname);
        }
        else if(isExpanded){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
        }
        return drawerView;
    }
```